# Excel - data in rows rather than columns / Lookup

Tags: arrays, excel, matrix, indexing, match

1 worksheet has data as such:-
   A.       B.
1  H7      £123
2  B1      £99
3  G2      £123
4  E9      £67

2nd worksheet is as so:-

```
 A.        B.      C.      D.     E.
```

1 £123     A1      G2       H7
   2 £99      B1      H3
   3 £67      F4      E9       L6     R3

The outcome I want is in Worksheet 1, to look at the order number in column A and find it in Worksheet 2 and return the value in column A. e.g. order num E9 in Worksheet 1 is £67 (cell B4). This is located in Worksheet 2 (cell C3) but should return the value from the same row in column A e.g. £67. I can then reconcile the 2 worksheets to investigate variances. Hope this is clearer (sorry for initial post).

Comment: Why `MATCH` is not working for you? Are the values in the second worksheet repeated? i.e. can you find G2 in different rows?

Comment: What is it that you want?  What is your expected outcome?  There is no question.  Please update the Original Post using edit, with the expected output and question.

Comment: Try googling 'Excel Index function' and 'Excel Match function'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula,

```
=INDEX(Sheet4!A:A,IFERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet4!B:B,0),IFERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet4!C:C,0),IFERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet4!D:D,0),IFERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet4!E:E,0),"no match")))),1)
```

Paste this in cell C1 of sheet 1 and drag till end. It searches the values in Sheet 4 and returns the 67 and so on.... Let me know if you neen anything else